# CakePHP - Find and count how many associated records exist

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to perform a search which as a condition it must return only records with **a certain amount of associated records**.

Currently I have one model (Bands) and one associated model thourgh hasmany (Songids). Each band can have many songids.

In this particular search I want to return 4 results of bands where those bands have **at least** 10 associated songids.

I tried to perform this with "HAVING" condition in the find procedure and virtualfields in the songid model with "COUNT(Songid.band_id)" but it only returns the total, not just for the selected field.

How can i achieve this? I was thinking of something like:

```
    $random = $this->Band->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('Band.band'),
            'order' => 'rand()',
            'limit' => 4,
            'contain' => array(
                'Songid' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'band_id COUNT' => 2)
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Last part "'band_id COUNT' => 2" should do the trick but I can't make it work. **Any ideas?**

---

EDIT: I could do a find all and then a foreach with a count for each associated model, but i'm looking for a "one find, no processing" solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'band_id COUNT' => 2` is not something the CakePHP ORM would understand, if at all you'd have to use a proper SQL snippet like `COUNT(table) >= x`.

However `conditions` always map to `WHERE`, and `WHERE COUNT` doesn't work in MySQL (which you are probably aware of as you've mentioned using `HAVING`).

Anways...

## Counter cache

In this particular situation you could make use of a [**counter cache**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count) field

```
class Songid extends AppModel {
    // ...

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Band' => array(
            'counterCache' => true,
        )
    );

    // ...
}
```

that way you can easily query by the number of associated records using a simple condition like:

```
$this->Band->find('all', array(
    // ...
    'conditions' => array(
        'Band.songid_count >=' 10
    )
));
```

## Use joins

When not using a counter, you'll have to join in the associated tables manually as they are not included automatically, but rather used in separate queries.

- **[Error with a query across two Models of a Plugin - CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741801/error-with-a-query-across-two-models-of-a-plugin-cakephp/23742882#23742882)**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables**

Once joined in you can safely query on the associated model:

```
$this->Band->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'songids',
            'alias' => 'Songid',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Band.id = Songid.band_id')
        )
    ),
    // ...
    'group' => 'Band.id HAVING COUNT(Songid.id) >= 10'
));
```

Comment: If I choose to add the countercache option, this number is going to be updated automatically even if i delete individual records of the related model? For example, from time to time i have to delete some records of the songid database through $this->Band->Songid->delete. Is this going to update that cache? BTW im asking just by curiosity, i went to the manual join solution and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it worked perfectly in local. When i uploaded to the production server (which bands has 10k records and songids have 100k records) i crashed the website. Guess im going to try the countercache solution!

Comment: @Andres Yes, that's exactly what counter cache does. 10K/100K shouldn't crash the server, but it might be a little slow as it needs to process _all_ rows for counting and random ordering. Using a properly indexed counter cache should be faster (assuming there are less than 10K bands with 10+ songs) as it will reduce the set before ordering, and of course there's no need for counting anymore.