# Select records which have atleast one hasMany relation row in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, associations, model-associations

I'm facing a problem with cakephp associations in Models.

I have to Select records which have atleast one hasMany reation row

**Model**

```
class Category extends AppModel 
{  
    public $hasMany = array(
             'Product' => array(         
             'className' => 'Product',
             'foreignKey' => 'CategoryId',                
             )              
        );
    }
```

**Query**

```
$categories = $this->Category->find('all');
```

I only needed the categories which have atleast one product entry

Categories Like : Shirts, Footwear, Glasses etc

Products like :

Small, medium, large (Shirts) 
With Frame, UV protected (Glass)

So, i jus want to get Shirts and Glasses Categories only because for the above example there is no products for Footwear

Comment: No code ,, No answer .

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird : Sorry, please check now

Comment: `I only needed the categories which have atleast one product entry` means ? i dont know what is ur Category table structure,where is product field.make it clear

Comment: i dunno if i understand what you are trying to say,i would suggest move your find to the product model and tell it to retrieve every product that has atleast 1 category,using the ` group by category_id `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use counterCache or joins

Please refer to **[CakePHP - Find and count how many associated records exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815890/cakephp-find-and-count-how-many-associated-records-exist/23821395#23821395)**

The most simple way with the best performance would be using a properly indexed counter cache field as shown in the linked answer.

Sice the linked answer is not an exact duplicate with respect to the join, here's some additional info, instead of using `HAVING COUNT` with the join you'd use a `IS NOT NULL` condition. Here's an (untested) example:

```
$this->Category->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'products',
            'alias' => 'Product',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Category.id = Product.CategoryId')
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Product.CategoryId IS NOT NULL'
    )
    'group' => 'Category.id'
));
```

Depending on the used DBMS and version you might get better performance using an inner join:

```
$this->Category->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'products',
            'alias' => 'Product',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array('Category.id = Product.CategoryId')
        )
    ),
    'group' => 'Category.id'
));
```