# How can I search in Has many association in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.3

I have three table

```
users(id,email, password,created) 
user_addresses(id,user_id,first_name,last_name)
user_companies(id,user_id,name,address)
```

And association are: 
user hasOne address
user hasMany companies

Now i want to search on user table and display only that records where search keyword matched in `(Company.name,User.email,UserAddress.first_name,UserAddress.last_name)`

Comment: You have to use explicit joins: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741801/error-with-a-query-across-two-models-of-a-plugin-cakephp/23742882**

Answer (score -1):

I think the below code is what you are looking for assuming the models have association defined in it:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Company.name' => '...', 'User.name' => '...', 'UserAddress.first_name' => '...', 'UserAddress.last_name' => '...'), 'recursive' => 2));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: you have to give me your code so that I can help you, in pagination also you can search