# Cakephp contain is included in query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, containable

When I run the following code the Containable behaviour does not work. **I don't want to use a manual join!**

```
$data = $this->Variant->find('first', array(
        'contain' => array('VariantValue'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Variant.product_id' => $product_id
        ),
        'group' => 'VariantValue.variant_id having count(*) = 2'
));
```

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE `variants` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL
)    

CREATE TABLE `variant_values` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `variant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

**The models:**

```
class Variant extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
         )
    );
    public $hasMany = array('CartVariant', 'VariantValue');
}

class VariantValue extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Value' => array(
            'className' => 'Value',
            'foreignKey' => 'value_id'
        ),
        'Variant' => array(
            'className' => 'Variant',
            'foreignKey' => 'variant_id'
        )
    );
}
```

**The error message:**

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column VariantValue.variant_id in group statement

SQL Query: 
SELECT Variant.id, Variant.product_id, Variant.price FROM variants AS Variant WHERE Variant.product_id = 1 GROUP BY VariantValue.variant_id having count(*) = 2

Comment: Please share your table structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with a query across two Models of a Plugin - CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741801/error-with-a-query-across-two-models-of-a-plugin-cakephp)

Comment: Could be a duplicate but I don't want to use a manual join if there is something like Containable in the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the code from the VariantValue perspective:

```
$data = $this->Variant->VariantValue->find('first', array(
        'contain' => array(
              'Variant' => array(
                  'conditions' => array('Variant.product_id' => $product_id))),
        'group' => 'VariantValue.variant_id HAVING count(*) = 2'
));
```