# Search & Pagination plugins together in CakePHP not integrating with HasMany in my Model

Tags: cakephp, search, plugins, model

I use the SearchDC plugin for search and the Pagination plugin.
I got in an action in the Controller to show the Users and I have a tick box if the user want to view only the Online Users. For that I use the UserLogin table and I check if the user been online in the last 1/2 hour.

```
    $this->User->bindModel(array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'UserLogin' => array(
                'className' => 'UserLogin',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'UserLogin.lastaction_timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)',
                    'UserLogin.logout_timestamp is null',
                ),
            )
        )

    ), false);
    $this->{$this->modelClass}->data[$this->modelClass] = $this->passedArgs;
    if ($this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->attached('Searchable')) {
        $parsedConditions = $this->{$this->modelClass}->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
    } else {
        $parsedConditions = array();
    }
    $parsedConditions = array_merge($parsedConditions,array('User.status' => '1'));
    $this->Paginator->settings[$this->modelClass]['contain'] = array( 'UserDetail.first_name',
        'UserDetail.last_name', 'UserDetail.institution_type', 'UserLogin'
    );
    $this->Paginator->settings[$this->modelClass]['conditions'] = $parsedConditions;
    $users = $this->paginate();
    $this->set(compact('users'));
```

I tried to add a condition to filter the non relevant from UserLogin table, but the result I checked using DebugKit of the query is not to have the UserLogin joined to the User table, which is good. Otherwise I'll get multiple entries.

What I try to achieve is to get rid of the rows with Users without any result in UserLogin. I thought to use contain behaviour but it didn't work. Also thought to use Hash, but then I'll destroy the Pagination.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use hasMany this way. See this pretty detailed answer of the very same problem:

[Error with a query across two Models of a Plugin - CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741801/error-with-a-query-across-two-models-of-a-plugin-cakephp/23742882)

It doesn work because (taken from the answer above):

> The first query retrieves the main model data but doesn't join in
>   associated tables, while the second one uses the IDs from the first
>   queries results to fetch the associated records, which are then merged
>   into the results.

Comment: I would go to manual join and I started doing that, but the issue is handling the different scenarios of selection in the Search Plugin. The problem with using Model B to query (The BelongsTo) that there are others models associated to Users. What about SubQuery or Custom Find are they suitable for that job?

Comment: Go for a custom find type and use that with the paginator. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination The search plugin contains at least one example that show how to build "complex" conditions, read the documentation.

Comment: I was asked to have a quick solution so decided to go on a hack rather than writing custom pagination. thanks for the directions.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go at the end with a quick solution, not the nicest one, but works.

```
    $this->{$this->modelClass}->data[$this->modelClass] = $this->passedArgs;
    if ($this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->attached('Searchable')) {
        $parsedConditions = $this->{$this->modelClass}->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);
        if (isset($this->passedArgs['is_online']) && $this->passedArgs['is_online'] === '1')
```

Which allows me to have to different queries. I added to one of them

```
$this->Paginator->settings[$this->modelClass]['joins'] with 
$this->Paginator->settings[$this->modelClass]['group']
```