# containable behavior in CakePHP is not working as expected

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

my database tables look like this:

```
chapters
********
id
name
chapter_id

workpackages
*******
id
name
chapter_id

requirements
******
id
name
workpackage_id
project_id

projects
*******
id
name
```

my model associations look like this:

```
Chapter Model
*************
public $hasMany= array(
    'Workpackage' => array(
        'className'  => 'Workpackage'
        'foreignKey' => 'chapter_id'
    'Chapter' => array(
        'className'  => 'Chapter'
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    )
);
Workpackage Model
************
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Chapter' => array(
        'className'  => 'Chapter'
        'foreignKey' => 'chapter_id'
    )
);
public $hasMany = array(
    'Requirement' => array(
        'className'  => 'Requirement'
        'foreignKey' => 'workpackage_id'
    )
);
Requirement Model
************
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className'  => 'Project'
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
    )
    'Workpackage' => array(
        'className'  => 'Workpackage'
        'foreignKey' => 'workpackage_id'
    )
);
Project Model
************
public $hasMany= array(
    'Requirement' => array(
        'className'  => 'Requirement'
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
    )
);
```

I have set each of the four models to use the Containable behaviour using:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

In my Chapters/index I want to show all the Chapters with it's Workpackages and Chapters of one specific Project
Everything I've tried so far has issued me Database Errors.

The current status of my ChaptersController index function looks like this:

```
$chapters = $this->Chapter->find('threaded', array(
    'conditions' => array('Requirement.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array('Workpackage' => 'Chapter.name')
));
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what getting error??

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: Unknown column 'Requirement.id'

Comment: You need to associate  `Requirement` with `Chapter` model.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will work with these associations

Comment: No it wont, the associations are too far away from each other.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but in the ends its the same problem [Error with a query across two Models of a Plugin - CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741801/error-with-a-query-across-two-models-of-a-plugin-cakephp)